# GSON Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, gson

I'm trying to parse a gson string to my java class, but because of the photo I keep receiving exceptions.

I'm using MySQL, With a Blob column for the images.

My java Class in Android and server is like this

```
public class Cliente {

    private Integer id;
    private byte[] foto;
    private String nome;
    private Date data_nascimento;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private boolean ativo;
    private Date data_cadastro;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public byte[] getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Date getData_nascimento() {
        return data_nascimento;
    }

    public void setData_nascimento(Date data_nascimento) {
        this.data_nascimento = data_nascimento;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }

    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

    public Date getData_cadastro() {
        return data_cadastro;
    }

    public void setData_cadastro(Date data_cadastro) {
        this.data_cadastro = data_cadastro;
    }


}
```

JSON String List (with NULL on the foto field, because of limited characters)

```
[{"id":1,"foto":null,"nome":"Guilherme","data_nascimento":"1993-12-23","endereco":"Rua Jornalista Angelo Zanuzzi, 560","telefone":"37055056","ativo":true,"data_cadastro":"2015-08-26"},{"id":2,"foto":null,"nome":"Lucas","data_nascimento":"2015-09-02","endereco":"Rua Jornalista Angelo Zanuzzi, 560","telefone":"37055056","ativo":true,"data_cadastro":"2015-08-26"}]
```

Parsing

```
ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = Rest.makeRequest("services/clientes", HttpMethod.GET, null);
clienteList = gson.fromJson(responseEntity.getBody().toString(), new TypeToken<List<Cliente>>() {
```

With NULL on foto field, the gson does great, but when an image comes from my DB, it throws the following exception

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 18 path $[0].foto
```

I can't figure out how to parse my string to a byte array!

**EDIT**

My JSON is correct, when i copy / paste I forgot to put [].

This is the begining of the Json with the image (blob) from mysql/hibernate

I can't post the entire code because of the lenght

```
[{"id":1,"foto":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QA2UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAABkcAmcAFEphUnk5alpFY3RFUWo5Zy1adUxSAP/iC/hJQ0NfUFJPRklMRQABAQAAC+gAAAAAAgAAA
```

Then, when GSON tries to convert, I get the error.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 18 path $[0].foto
```

The problem is, HIBERNATE is sending foto as STRING instead of BYTE[] Array

Then, when I try to parse, GSON throwns the exception.
If I Change in my Android Model foto to String (private String foto), the gson parse correctly, but I cant figure out how to put this "byte string" into an imageview.

I want to recieve the byte[] to set it into an imageview

Comment: Please post some of your relevant codes and may be the json string too

Comment: Json string is too big to post ( 7342 caracteres because of the image ), I will update with the code.

Comment: i had the same issue it turned out that the server response was coming as a string and as an array for some other

Comment: Is the JSON structure is correct? If yes it is not a valid json

Comment: why you don't have a  JsonArray?? like this [ {"id":1,...,...},{"id":2,....."} ]  or that's your real json.  you have {"id":1,...,...},{"id":2,....."}  or that you just missed in your comment?

Comment: lucas "foto":null for any of the item in json is it array...bcoz if it was array it should have been "foto":[//then objects] in json....Also you have taken it as byte[] foto; hence it expects foto to be array but it is getting string...So first check the all foto in json and let me know...

Comment: Updated the post.

I just post the begining of the JSON that hibernate send me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Actually,  the Hibernate sends the foto data back as a String, so I have to alter my model in android to be

```
private String foto;
```

instead of

```
private byte[] foto;
```

And, before turn it into my ImageView, I must decode the string with

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(itemCardCliente.getFoto(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```